# Subir varios proyectos a GitHub

Tags: github

he subido un proyecto a **GitHub** después de crear un repositorio, la duda que tengo es

- ¿si tengo que crear un repositorio por proyecto o en un mismo repositorio puedo subir varios proyectos?.

Gracias

Comment: te sugiero revisar : https://hashnode.com/post/choosing-between-one-project-per-repository-vs-multiple-projects-per-repository-architecture-cj8kmhmdy012800wu62v3x48v

Comment: De las dos formas es posible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomendaría **NO** poner varios proyectos en el mismo repositorio, debido a que a cada proyecto puedes configurarle de manera independiente:

- la licencia de uso
- la integración continua ([azure pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/?nav=min)[travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci)[appveyor](/questions/tagged/appveyor)[circleci](/questions/tagged/circleci))
- Estándares de calidad ([bestpractices](https://bestpractices.coreinfrastructure.org/es) [david-dmm](https://david-dm.org/)[codacy](/questions/tagged/codacy))
- Cobertura del codigo ([coveralls](/questions/tagged/coveralls))
- Estadísticas por repositorio ([isitmaintained](https://isitmaintained.com/))
- otras ([codetriage](https://www.codetriage.com/))

Ahora para casos excepcionales, como que se trate de que sean proyectos interdependientes y que los cambios en uno afecten al otro, tienes principalmente dos opciones

1. Si eres un experto usando [git](/questions/tagged/git) puedes crear repositorios enlazados llamados [submódulos](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), en los que mandas un sobproyecto a su propio repositorio, pero aún puedes ver el original y navegar por todo el código
2. Usar una solución programática multilenguaje en un único repositorio (por ejemplo: [bazel](/questions/tagged/bazel))

Answer (score 0):

puedes subirlos todos en un solo repositorio.

ejem:

```
proyectos
|-->proyecto1
|-->proyecto2
|-->proyecto3
|-->proyecton
```

Donde bien puedes tener inicializado git en **proyectos** y subir todos tus proyectos a un solo repositorio o inicializar git en cada proyecto y subirlo individualmente. O tambien puedes combinar ambas iniciar git en una carpeta contenedora de proyectos e ir registrando a su vez tus cambios en cada proyecto que gustes, posteriormente solo subirias el proyecto principal sim embargo deberias ser mucho más cuidadoso con lo que es tu archivo gitignore pues este va hacer caso al proyecto principal y no a los secundarios.